# Eclipse: Selenium Libraries Import issue

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver, libraries

Am trying to add Selenium libraries in my project but it is displaying ***The import org cannot be resolved***

Note: added all the external libraries properly.

[This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhMx8.jpg) please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a best way to avoid this error is to install fresh eclipse  and initialize new project and path. Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Hi @zsbappa Thankyou for your reply, Issue is resolved. Issue was with Java version, I was using Java 10.1 because of that it was showing error now i have selected Java 1.8 and it is working fine.